# Erro no console google-charts?

Tags: google-charts, console

Os gráficos são desenhados corretamente no html, porém fica esse erro no console.

> VM6537:108 Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

```
/*Graficos*/
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartTicketsByClient);

function drawChartTicketsByClient() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/client/ajax",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false
    }).responseJSON;

    var dataArray = [
        ['Name', 'Tickets'],
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var row = [jsonData[i].Name, jsonData[i].Tickets];
        dataArray.push(row);
    }
    var options = {
        title: 'Tickets por cliente',
        curveType: 'function',
        series:{0 :{"color":'#57c8f2'}}
    };

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

//**************************//
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartTicketsByType);

function drawChartTicketsByType() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/ticket/ajax",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false
    }).responseJSON;

    var dataArray = [
        ['Description', 'Tickets'],
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var row = [jsonData[i].Description, jsonData[i].Tickets];
        dataArray.push(row);
    }
    var options = {
        title: 'Tickets por tipo',
        curveType: 'function',
        series:{0 :{"color":'#E9D460'}}
    };

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_ticket'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

//**************************//
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartTicketsByTerm);

function drawChartTicketsByTerm() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/ticket/term-on/ajax",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false
    }).responseJSON;


    var dataArray = [
        ['Name', 'Tickets'],
        ['No prazo', jsonData[0][0].Tickets],
        ['Fora do prazo', jsonData[1][0].Tickets],
    ];


    var options = {
        title: 'Tickets por prazo',
        curveType: 'function',
        series:{0 :{"color":'#57c8f2'},
                1: {"color": '#ff6c60'}}
    };

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_ticket_term'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Alguém sabe dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Não vejo a palavra `Container` nesse código. Qual é a linha `108`?

Comment: Este que é o problema, não se vê por que não tem kkkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema, eu estava chamando essas funções mesmo que o id não existisse na view html, a solução foi dividir em mais de um arquivo e importar os arquivos em suas respectivas views.